# When we hit the debug button in visual studio SSIS project - does it run in 32 or 64 bit mode - and is 32bit provider compatible with 64bit run mode?

Tags: visual-studio, ms-access, ssis, oledb, 32bit-64bit

I have a new VM on which I have installed Visual studio.

I created a new SSIS project, and am trying to use the oledb data source task to access an .accdb MS-Access file.

However I cannot see the Provider. So I installed the Access 32 bit runtime. Now I can see the provider. I am reading that since visual studio is a 32-bit tool, we have to install the Access 32bit runtime. Otherwise if we install the 64bit runtime, then we will not be able to see the provider in the list because visual studio is 32bit and only shows 32bit providers.

When I hit the debug button in visual studio SSIS project it can access the MS-Access file. I am now confused and want to ask - when the project is running, does it run in 32 or 64 bit mode? If the answer is 64bit mode, then how can it access the MS-access file using the 32bit provider? Does it mean that project running in 64 bit mode can utilize 32 bit mode runtime/provider?

Assuming no settings are changed, when debug button is pressed, then does the program execute is 32 or 64 bit mode? Does the OS bitness have any impact on this?

Answer (score 1):

You are quite right and quite close here.

Since Visual Studio is x32 bits?

Well, if your project is set to x86 (x32 bits) or set to ANY CPU?

Then hitting F5 to run + debug (or ctrl-F5 to run the .exe without debug), then you will get (have) a x32 bit running program. Some caution here. If you use ANY cpu? then again FROM VS f5 to run - you get a x32 bit process.

But, if you go to the windows commnd line?
Well, if you launch teh windows x64 bit command line (default on most computers), then if the project is ANY cpu? Then your app run will be x64 bits. (and ANY un-manged code such as Access, or any other windows code used for COM autoamtion? it will break.

If you launch the windows x32 bit command line (with any CPU) then you get a x32 bit version running.

So, from VS - F5 - always x32 bits.
From windows command line - depends.

So, what above suggests? Well, if your intention is to have + use x32 bits process? Then FORCE/SET the project to your intentions. That way, no "by chance" will fool you, and your application will ALWAYS run as to the project settings.

So, in such cases, I do avoid ANY CPU.

Now, what happens if you force the project to x64 bits? eg this:

[image]

Well, if you pick x64 bits? (and not any cpu, and not x86).

Then hitting f5 (or ctrl-F5), it WILL run the application as a x64 bits in-process. I am not sure quite how VS works, but they have some kind of "bridge" that marshals the x64 bit debugger to talk to VS x32 bits.

So, if you force the project to x64, then it will always run as x64 bit - including from VS.

So, this means:

```
if you set project to x64 bits - use a connection builder in settings?
You can use the connection builder but since (we assume) that you using
```

access x64 bits? Then the test connection button in VS will NEVER work.

But, if you run the code as x64, and have access x64, then it will work. So ONLY the test connection button fails - and that's due to VS being x32.

If you have even the wrong version of Access (say x32 bits), and your project is set to x64? Then the connection builders will work and EVEN the test connection will work (because test connection is ALWAYS x32 bits from VS). This has the effect of you building a connection, hitting test connection - it says good!!! But when you run the project (f5, ctrl-f5), the project runs as x64, and it will fail (this example assumes x32 bits).

Now this is building an writing code from VS. I don't' know of a SSIS package built with Visual Studio works different. But we do NOT want to confuse Visual Studio (VS) with that of say sql studio or other systems - they don't have the project "cpu" or "bit" setting options like you do for a VS project.

So, I quite much suggest if your intention is x32 bit operations, then ALWAYS force the VS project to x32 bits, and thus come time to launch that .exe from windows, then it will never run with a wrong or un-expected bit size.

I not tested a SISIS integration project, but if building this from VS? Then once again, force/set the project bit size.

In effect to remove the "chance" of the wrong bit size? Then force the project to the given bit size you as the developer were intending to use here - that way this is not left to chance.

There ARE times when you want to use ANY cpu. A really good example is when you build say class library code to share amoung projects. In that case, ANY cpu is a good choice, since then EVEN projects forced to x32 or x64 can referances those external assemblies and library code.

However, if you force those external assemblies to a given bit size, then only projects running that that correct bit size can consume such libraries.

.net code (managed) is differnt then un-managed code. .net code has the ability to run "either" x32 or x64 if you choose ANY cpu. But un-managed code (external non .net code such as Access) can't change on the fly like .net code can. And I use the term "on the fly lose here". Since ONCE a .net program starts running x32 or x64? It remains that bit size until terminated.

So, ANY CPU is fine for external class library code you write and thus want to include in any project. But the main project .exe program has to use SOME external non .net (non managed) code? Then you would do very well to force the project bit size settings.

And to answer you last question?

If the provider is a .net one, such as sql provider or whatever? Then it is managed code - cpu settings don't matter. it is ONLY when you start using external code systems that are NOT managed and NOT .net code. MS-Access is one such common example. So would be any windows c++ or even a lot of commerial programs.

For example. Sage/Simply accoutning, and Quickbooks accounting? They offer .net SDK's to interface to those accoutning packages. But they only have x32 bit verisons of those desktop programs - and they are not .net prorgrams. So once agian, you do well to force the project to x32 bits.

So, no x64 bit process can consume a x32 bit process. nor can you consume external librares that don't match.

However, if that library code and system is .net (managed code), and was compiled and created with any CPU, then you don't have any restrictions in regards to using ANY cpu, or even consuming those libraires when you force the .net project cpu settings.

So this whole system ONLY breaks down when you introduce or start using external code libraires.

For example, if you use .net ghostscript library? They have two versions - x32 and x64. And thus just like MS-Access you have to match up the bit size of those external libraries.

This actually is a REALLY nasty problem say for Adobe PDF. Their pdf viewers are x32 only. In fact it was only what - last month they started offering x64 bit versions of their PDF adobe reader. And they no doubt started doing this since office is now moving towards being x64 bits and not a x32 bit system/program.

Comment: By default, assuming no settings are changed, when debug button is pressed, then does the program execute is 32 or 64 bit mode? Does the OS bitness have any impact on this?

Comment: default is ANY cpu, hence with above information, you ALWAYS get a x32 in-process running instance of your applcation. thus doing nothing and that means default of ANY CPU and thus you will always get a x32 bit running application. And no, OS bitness will not change this. The only issue of OS bits of course if the PC was a x32 bit OS, then of course the x64 bit project settings could never be used. But as noted, if you run the .exe from outside of VS, then ANY CPU means the project will run based on which version of the command line prompt you launch (there are two of them x32 and x64 cmd.exe)

Comment: But if you just double clicked on a shortcut to that .exe? You in most cases get a x64 bit version running if you  project setting is ANY. So ANY cpu = always x32 when launched from VS. But that same .exe when launched from windows command line, or clicked on from the file explore will near always launch as x64 bits. So ANY CPU takes on the "process" or system that launches the .exe. So launched from VS - x32. Launched from file explore and not from VS - you get a x64 bit version running.

Comment: Of course if the OS is x32, then from VS or from the command line (or file explorer) then it will always be x32, and you can't ever run the .exe as x64 on a x32 only OS.

Comment: In my project properties the debug setting shows 64 bit. But I don't have access 64bit access run time. So i am confused how it is able to read the msaccess file

Comment: When you run the code, it would not be able to read + use Access. However, as i stated, while this can't work, the test connection buttion in VS will work, but that means nothing here, since when you run the code, it would not work. If you can open + read access file with the project set to x64, then you must have access x64 installed. And it not really Access that matters, it the ACE data engine that matters - and that can be installed without Access. So don't confuse a test connection in the VS builders - they mean ZERO here!!! You can ONLY know if this will work by running the project (f5)

Comment: So the test connection in the VS builders means ZERO ZERO ZERO here. They don't matter and MEAN NOTHING. You can ONLY know and actually REALLY test this by running your code. If your code project as x64 works, then you MUST have ACE x64 installed. There no other possible answer. But just 100% ignore the test connection button in VS - they MEAN NOTHING when using x64 bits and you can't use nor rely on them in ANY WHAT what so ever. again: WHEN project is x64, the ONLY way to test for a valid connection is to run the code/project. Ignore all other possible information.

Comment: By test connection do you mean debug button? Is there bitness difference between the play button and running in debug mode?

Comment: No - "test" connection is a option when you say use project settings to seutp + build a conneciton string. When you used the VS connection string builder (say from project settings), then you have a chance/option when setting up a connection to hit "test connection" button.  So, for x64 bits? F5 to run - (or ctrl F5)  means you run the project - and thus the x64 bit connection should work when you run code, or debug code - it don't matter. But OFTEN people use project->settings, and hit that test connection button when using connection builder (has zero to do with running or debugging code).

Comment: so play/run/debug/f5 - all the same - and since it looks like your NOT using the connection builder(s), then it don't matter.

Comment: When you say "if you launch teh windows x64 bit command line" - what command do you type in the command line?

Comment: keep in mind when I state the x64 bit command line? I mean the windows one, not the VS one. But yes. if you tap windows key, and then type in cmd, your first choice is the command prompt. This will in most cases launch the x64 bit version of windows command prompt. If you want the x32 bit one, then type in this: c:\windows\syswow64\cmd.exe

Comment: I want to understand what you would type INSIDE the command line please.

Comment: After you compile and create "yourprogram.exe". file in the bin folder. Then launch x32 or x64 bits command line. So how to run any .exe program in windows, or a "dir" command, or anything else. You are 100% free to type in any command you want - including "yourprogram.exe".  As noted, if you use "any cpu " then what bit size the program runs will be determined by x32/x64 command prompt used. I mean, if you create a shortcut to the .exe file, then you don't care. But from command prompt it does matter.